# preparedStatement setting null for NUMBER_ARRAY doesnt work

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

```
ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor =
    ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("NUMBER_ARRAY", conn);

if (parameter != null) {
    ARRAY oracleArray =
            new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, intList.toArray());
    ps.setArray(i, oracleArray);
} 
else {
    ps.setNull(i, Types.ARRAY, "NUMBER_ARRAY");
}
```

In the above code I was trying to set `oracleArray` the to null. It does'nt throw any exception. But Oracle doesnt take it as null I guess. What could be the way to pass in a null, I mean to set a list to null what a orcle DB could take it as `NUMBER_ARRAY(null)` which will be later passed to a Stored Procedure(SP). The SP is ready to take a null list. If it is a null list it returns nothing. And if it is not a null list it will give the results. this is a valid scenario.

Comment: Do you want the Oracle collection in the database to be null itself, or to be a collection of one element, where that element is null?

Comment: Basically I want oracle to take my parameter as NUMBER_ARRAY(null).

Comment: I want to pass in a null list from java to oracle stored procedure and that proc should take it as NUMBER_ARRAY(null).. I have run the stored proc by passing in NUMBER_ARRAY(null) and works fine. But when calling that SP from java passing in null list doesnt work. I know we can set a int to null as ps.setNull(i, int), but not sure how we can do for a BigInteger list from java. To your question I want oracle collection to be null it self. @rgettman

Comment: @Raj: you are contradicting yourself.  You say that if you pass your stored proc `NUMBER_ARRAY(null)` it works fine, yet you also say 'you want your collection to be null itself'.  `NUMBER_ARRAY(null)` is not a null collection, it is a 1-element collection containing a single `NULL` value.  Please clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: Sorry for my  statement. I did not realize that NUMBER_ARRAY(null) is equivalent to 1-element of a collection containing a single null. My problem here is I want to pass in a list which has no values added to it. SO my understanding is i need to pass in a list with 1-element as null to get this scenario worked.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: Thanks for your answer on the issue. This made me to simplify the problem. I want to rate your answer. But I have no option here to rate it or like it.

Comment: @Raj: I hadn't answered your question, I was trying to clarify.  I was trying to find out whether you wanted a null array or an array containing only a null value, but it seems the answer is neither.  Nonetheless, I have now written up an answer which may help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some confusion about null arrays, empty arrays and arrays that contain only a single `NULL` value.

A `NULL` array is the absence of an array, in the same way that a `NULL` number is the absence of a number.  An empty array is an array that exists, but has 0 elements in it.  Both are different from `NUMBER_ARRAY(null)`, which is an array that contains a single `NULL` value.

The `COUNT` method on an array, which returns the number of elements in the array, provides an illustration of the differences between these three.

Firstly, a `NULL` array:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_null_array     number_array  := null;
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || l_null_array.COUNT);
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Here, we get an error.  We can't find out how many elements there are in `l_null_array` because we don't have an array to find the number of elements of.

Secondly, an empty array:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_empty_array    number_array  := number_array();
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || l_empty_array.COUNT);
  5  end;
  6  /

Count: 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Here, we can find the number of elements in an empty array, and that number is zero.

Finally, an array containing only `NULL`:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_array_containing_null    number_array  := number_array(null);
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || l_array_containing_null.COUNT);
  5  end;
  6  /
Count: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This array has one element within it, and that one element is `NULL`.

Note that you can pass as many arguments as you like to the `NUMBER_ARRAY` constructor function, and these values will be the initial contents of the array.  For example, `NUMBER_ARRAY(1, 4, 18, 11, 22, 6)` creates a number array with 6 elements in it.

So, how can we set each kind of array using JDBC?

- To set a `NULL` array, use

  ```
  ps.setNull(i, Types.ARRAY, "NUMBER_ARRAY");
  ```

  as you have done above.
- For an empty array, use:

  ```
  ps.setArray(i, new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, new Integer[0]));
  ```
- For an array containing a single `NULL` value only, use

  ```
  ps.setArray(i, new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, new Integer[] { null }));
  ```

I'm using an `Integer` array in these examples, but other numeric types should work too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I that I was not able to explain you my question. I am using the scenario where in a list never been initialized. SO my scenario refers to your first one. Anyway I need to take all these options to the DB guy and figure out what way he is comfortable.